# "max_packet_size" variant in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering if there is a SQL Server "version" of the MySQL `max_packet_size` parameter. Is there a way to configure this setting in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Configure the network packet size Server Configuration Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177437.aspx):

```
sp_configure 'network packet size', ...;
```

But this setting is not the same as MySQL's [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet), is more similar to [`net_buffer_length`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length). SQL Server's maximum request limit is [65,536 * Network Packet Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), which is closer to `max_allowed_packet` meaning.